# How create crisp pixel border in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

How do I create this look in Illustrator: black single-pixel outer border, brighter inner single-pixel border? Example:

[image]

I've tried adding a black one-pixel path to white border in Illustrator but it ends up looking like this - not crisp:

[image]

I'd prefer to implement it in Illustrator, but please advise Photoshop solutions if you believe it's not possible in Illustrator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Draw the shape - black fill, black 1pt stroke.

Make certain "Align to Pixel Grid" is checked on the Transform panel.

Add a new stroke via the Appearance Panel. Set it to 1pt and white.

Choose Effect > Path > Offset Path and insert -1pt into the field.

[image]

Additional: You could simply create the inner stroke and set it to align inner via the Stroke Panel. However, when you use that method the inner stroke won't align to the pixel grid and will be off-center. Seems that may be a bug in the align to pixel feature.